# Why are some mice incompatible with Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to buy a new mouse for my office PC, but most of the more advanced mice (and gaming ones) say they're only compatible with windows. Why is that?

If I were to not need any of the advanced features of a mouse (RGB, key remapping etc), would any mouse work? Basically what I want to work is just pointing and clicking. More specifically, I'm interested in [this mouse](https://www.trust.com/en/product/21789-gxt-188-laban-rgb-mouse).

Comment: Hardware compatibility is determined entirely by the hardware manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, the basic features usually work. Only the proprietary stuff needs proprietary drivers/software. But if you only need the basic features what makes sense is to buy hardware that provides only those features. Likewise we don't buy a powerful gaming laptop with a brand new Nvidia graphics card just for web browsing, social media and Solitaire.

Comment: You will note manufacturer states MacOS isn't supported either. Only Windows 7/8/10. For people who want to play AAA PC games probably >95% use Windows. My advanced mouse $100 is compatible with Linux. But it's not a gaming mouse, it's a professional business mouse. You will notice a small percentage of questions in **Ask Ubuntu** deal with gaming problems.